# equal_to usage in C++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, generics, compare

I am confused on how to use this method. I tried the following:

```
std::equal_to(T objA, T objB);
```

I get errors if I use it like this. However, I have seen countless examples that use it like this:

```
pairs1 = mismatch(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
                  v2.begin(), 
                  equal_to<int>());
```

How is this method supposed to be used?

Sample Error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:25:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::equal_to<int>::equal_to(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>&)’
  pairs1 = equal_to<int>(v2, v1)); 
                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/random:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62,
                 from prog.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:352:12: note: candidate: constexpr std::equal_to<int>::equal_to()
     struct equal_to : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
            ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:352:12: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:352:12: note: candidate: constexpr std::equal_to<int>::equal_to(const std::equal_to<int>&)
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:352:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:352:12: note: candidate: constexpr std::equal_to<int>::equal_to(std::equal_to<int>&&)
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:352:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: Step 1 always is to read the errors.  If you don't understand the errors, and you post a question on Stack Overflow, then you include the errors in your question so we can read them for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought the point of equal_to was to be a generic version of an overloaded `==` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`equal_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) is not a function, you cannot call it directly like one. It's a class that has the `operator()` defined which means that you need to create an object and call `operator()` on that object.

Possible implementation:

```
template <class T = void>
struct equal_to {
    constexpr bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }
};
```

Usage example:

```
auto test()
{
    auto my_comp = equal_to<int>{};
    bool b1 =  my_comp(2, 3);

    // or create a temporary object and call it in one line:
    bool b2 = equal_to<int>{}(2, 3);
}
```

It also has a specialization that will deduce the arguments passed to `operator()`:

```
template <>
struct equal_to<void> {

    template <class T, class U>
    constexpr auto operator()(T&& lhs, U&& rhs) const
        -> decltype(std::forward<T>(lhs) == std::forward<U>(rhs))
    {
        return std::forward<T>(lhs) == std::forward<U>(rhs);
    }
};

auto test2()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    auto my_comp = equal_to<>{};

    bool b1 = my_comp(2, 3);
    bool b2 = my_comp("one string"s, "another string"s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the explanation I was looking for. it makes sense to me now.